# Update column by other column values in Scala Slick

Tags: scala, slick

Is there anyway to update column based on other column value in Slick2. In sql I would do it like this:

```
UPDATE table SET columna = columnb WHERE appropriate = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not using the "lifted embedded" (Scala collections style) of Slick.

You can:

- Use [plain SQL](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/sql.html) (the `sqlu` interpolator) to write your SQL to get that effect.
- Use client-side update, where you read the rows, and update each row, and send it back to the database (possibly inside a transaction). Which is probably not what you want to do, but is an option.

For the lifted-embedded style, Slick [issue 497](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/497) is worth tracking, as that's probably closest to the change you need.